# Creating a simple Node.js web service for use with AJAX

Tags: javascript, web-services, node.js, callback

I have a basic Node.js http server set up as per the docs, I'm trying to create a very simple web service I can talk to with Javascript (AJAX) which I'll then hook up to Arduino.  It's a test piece, I may go down the road of something else but this is proving to be fun.  Anyway, here is the server-side javascript:

```
var http = require('http');
var _return = 'Bing Bong';

  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/jsonp'});

    //do stuff
    res.end('_return(\'Hello :-)\' + _return)');
}).listen(process.env.VMC_APP_PORT || 1337, null);
```

And this is the client side:

```
function experimentFive(node) {
    console.log('X5 Func started');

    console.log('Calling Node.js service');

    var nodeURL = node;

    $.ajax({
        url: nodeURL,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "_return",
        cache: false,
        timeout: 50000,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Data is: ' + data);
            $("#nodeString").text(" ");
            $("#nodeString").append(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('error : ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

experimentFive('http://fingerpuk.eu01.aws.af.cm/');
```

This works, I get the data back but not as I'd expect.  What I'd like to be able to do is change some data server side and receive that back.  I get back the string in the res.end plus:

```
function () {
        responseContainer = arguments;
    }
```

Instead of the variable's data.  No matter how I try to get that data back, it is either undefined or this response.

From research I think the variable is not having it's data set before the callback fires, so it's empty.  But if I set an initial value the data is still undefined.

Am I missing something very simple here?  Should I just go back to C#?

Cheers.

Comment: Can you state exactly what data you get back? You may want to take another look at the formatting of our `res.end` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way of accomplishing this would be to use [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) with [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) to handle routing your endpoints. By doing this you can set up routes such as `GET /media/movies/`, fire an AJAX request to this route, then have it return JSON data that you can handle on your app.

Here's an example of ExpressJS routing in an app that I made:

```
var groups = require('../app/controllers/groups');

// find a group by email
app.post('/groups/find', groups.searchGroupsByEmail);
```

Here is a great tutorial that I used when getting started with Express. It walks through the entire process from installing Node.JS (which you've already done) to setting up the ExpressJS routing to handle incoming HTTP requests.

[Creating a REST API using Node.js, Express, and MongoDB](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/)